# How to remove jobs that have been added to the magento cron tasks by an extension that has been removed

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, system.log

I keep getting an error repeating in my system.log telling me the following:

ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Bronto/Common/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/app/code/local:/var/www/html/app/code/community:/var/www/html/app/code/core:/var/www/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

This was an extension used by Bronto email marketing software that we no longer use. I disabled the extension originally and then carefully went through and removed every file that I can see the extension installed (I went through comparing folder by folder to the install files).

However, something seems to still be called and I can't figure out how to track this back and remove it. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Looking at aoescheduler I can see several bronto% tasks scheduled. I have tried the following in mysql:

```
DELETE from cron_schedule WHERE job_code LIKE '%bront%';
```

However, this doesn't seem to totally remove the task or stop it (they stay in aoescheduler). I have disabled them from there but I want to understand how to completely remove these.

Comment: There may be an aoescheduler table in the database. Check there for any references to Bronto

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere in one of the configuration files there is still a rogue event observer referencing the Bronto/Observer model.

Have you checked all the configuration files for a reference to the bronto observer model?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ran sudo grep -lr 'Bronto' /var/www/html/ but that only came back with a couple of possible files. A few in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bronto and some files in /var/www/html/var/. I deleted the template files but I don't think they are creating the cron job.

Comment: All references need to be removed if you've uninstalled the module; otherwise, anything that reads the configuration will continue to look for it and try to use it.

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks but excuse my ignorance, I can't figure out where to look for references to it. I don't supposed you have idea where this might be or some way to track it backwards? I tried looking in cron_schedule and also searched the filesystem but just can't find any files that are hidden away.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I've never used the AOE extension, so I'm not sure how it caches anything.

Comment: Stange, I think the problem is they have injected something into Magento to keep this recurring but I'm not sure what or where.